# Calculating loan payment in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, keydown

I am making a loan payment calculator on my website (www.kreditrunner.dk - In the bottom of the page).

**EDIT:** Problem solved with the following equation:

```
var princ = document.getElementById("amount").value;
var intr = document.getElementById("earlypercent").value/1200;
var term = document.getElementById("time").value;

document.getElementById("result").value = princ * intr / (1 - (Math.pow(1/(1 + intr), term)));
```

And also i used a keyup function instead. Cause when the key is pressed down, the input hasn't received the value yet, hence the wrong result :)

**ORIGINAL POST:**

I have my four inputs with respectively amount, interest rate per year in percent, payment period, and result.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="150">
            <label for="amount">Lånebeløb (DKK)</label>
            <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" class="input-small">
            <label for="earlypercent">ÅOP (%)</label>
            <input type="text" id="earlypercent" name="earlypercent" class="input-small">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="time">Løbetid (Mdr)</label>
            <input type="text" id="time" name="time" class="input-small">
            <label for="result"><b>Månedlig betaling (DKK)</b></label>
            <input type="text" id="result" name="result" class="input-medium">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For each of the first three input I have the listed calculations seen below which is derived from the following equation: http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-a-Loan-Payment

```
$('#amount').keydown(function () {
    var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
    var earlypercent = document.getElementById("earlypercent").value;
    var monthlypercent = earlypercent / 12 * 100;
    var time = document.getElementById("time").value;
    var negativetime = time * (-1);
    var result = 1 + monthlypercent;
    result = Math.pow(result, negativetime);
    result = 1 - result;
    result = monthlypercent / result;

    document.getElementById("result").value = result * amount;
});
```

However, my result is weird as ****. As you can see when you try (e.g. with values, 1000, 10%, 12 months) the result is 8333.33 where it should have been around 83.33. Well actually it should be around 87.95.

So i could move the *100 in the montlypercent, however as you see when write an amount and tab to the next input field, the result changes even though the values are the same. Cant seem to get the equation right and the keydown function bothers me :/

Please help :)

Comment: Well if I fill that in I get 87.91588723000987
But when you put 10 where you should put 12, and visa versa you get hte 8333.333... etc

Comment: I just fixed it :D How can I delete the post?

Comment: Nice :) What was the problem?

Comment: The equation :) Se edited post

Comment: Post the solution as an answer (and accept that as the answer in a couple of days, when you're able), don't delete the question; Stack Overflow is meant to help future visitors, not just you.